# Showing text for a while

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/639RF/

```
$("button").click(function () {
    //#t holds 'X'
    $('#t').fadeOut(1000).text('ZZ').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#t').delay(1000);
    $('#t').fadeOut(1000).text('YY').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

I'm trying to show some text for a while, then replacing it with some other text.
The way I was trying to do it ignores the first text I am trying to show, and replacing it with the last one from the beginning.

It should:

Fade 'X' out,
Fade 'ZZ' in,
hold for a second
Fade 'ZZ' out,
Fade 'YY' in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `$("#t")`, you are creating a new jQuery object. That object may have the same element, but it is still a different object with different properties.

Try this:

```
var t = $("#t");
t.fadeOut(1000,function() {t.text("ZZ")}).fadeIn(1000);
t.delay(1000);
t.fadeOut(1000,function() {t.text("YY")}).fadeIn(1000);
```

Edit again: [Figured it out!](http://jsfiddle.net/639RF/2/) You need to use the animation callback to handle things that aren't normally part of the animation queue.

Comment: Yeah, `text()` will not respect `delay()`, which only applies to animations.

Comment: Yeah, does the same. html() does as well.

Comment: See edit. I'm happy now! Still won't touch jQuery with a 50-foot pole, but I had a 100-foot pole this time so it's okay.

Comment: Does work! assigning $('#t') to a variable makes no difference though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks as a second parameter to `fadeOut` and `FadeIn`, also to wait for a second, you can also use the raw `setInterval` method.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var $dom = $('#t');

        $dom.fadeOut(1000, function(){ //first, fades out.
            $dom.text('ZZ').fadeIn(1000,function(){ //changes the text to ZZ,

                var $wait = setInterval(function(){ //wait for a second
                    clearInterval($wait); //prevent the loop of waiting

                    $dom.fadeOut(1000,function(){ //fadeout for a second
                        $dom.text('YY').fadeIn(1000); //change the text into YY, and fade in
                    });

                },1000);

            });
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/639RF/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/639RF/3/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Note: feel free change the duration as you like.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/639RF/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $('#t').fadeOut(500, function(){ //fadeout in half a second and when complete
            //fadein in half a second, wait for 2 seconds, when complete
            $(this).text('ZZ').fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function(){
                //fadein in half a second
                $(this).text('YY').fadeIn(500)
            });
        });
    });
});
```